# echo an external link - email (mailto:) from Custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

I've currently got something like...

```
<?php
    $url = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'email_address', true);
    if (!empty($url))
    {
?>
<img src="/wp-content/themes/ibusiness/img/mail.png">
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">Email Organisation</a>
<p>'<?php
    }
?>
```

Whilst this does display as I'd expect the output is a link with the email address appended to the end of the current URL - anywhere I try to add mailto: just breaks the code.

Comment: How about `<?php echo esc_attr('mailto:' . $url); ?>`?

Comment: if it's appened to the end of the current url then there's an issue with one of youe functions, you only want the email address returned

Comment: @Vector: remember how relative URLs work. If `$url` is `"foo@example.com"`, then the browser will interpret and display the URL as `"http://www.current-site.com/current-page/foo@example.com"`.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">Email Organisation</a>
```

By

```
<a href="mailto:<?php echo $url; ?>">Email Organisation</a>
```

It might work.

Comment: That would work if the url that is being generated was correct